# Custom Instrumentation in New Relic: Which assemblyName should I use with C# Web Forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, newrelic

I've searched high and low here on SO and also read ALL of the pertinent documentation on New Relic's site.

I am attempting to capture method-specific information in the New Relic transaction trace from my C#.Net Web Forms page, but cannot find an example *anywhere* that uses both of these technologies together. I'm pretty sure that my problem is that I don't know which `assemblyName` to use.  Here's a working example where I'm hoping to get the details about the method `SleepForFive()`:

**TestNewRelic.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="TestNewRelic.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sandbox_TestNewRelic" %>
<html>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnFiveSeconds" runat="server" OnClick="btnFiveSeconds_Click" Text="Sleep for 5" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestNewRelic.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public partial class Sandbox_TestNewRelic : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void btnFiveSeconds_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SleepForFive();
        lblResult.Text = "Done";
    }

    public void SleepForFive() { Thread.Sleep(5000); }

}
```

**DotNetInstrumentation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension xmlns="urn:newrelic-extension">
  <instrumentation>
    <tracerFactory >
      <match assemblyName="" className="Sandbox_TestNewRelic">
        <exactMethodMatcher methodName="SleepForFive"/>
      </match>
      <match assemblyName="System.Web" className="System.Web.UI.Page">
        <exactMethodMatcher methodName="FrameworkInitialize" />
        <exactMethodMatcher methodName="OnInit" />
      </match>
    </tracerFactory>
  </instrumentation>
</extension>
```

**My Result**

[Please click this link to see the output from New Relic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUNkU.png) (not enough reputation to post it here...)

**Summary**

As you can see in the image, the Custom Instrumentation is working -- I'm getting the two `System.Web` methods I asked for --  What am I missing?

***What must I change to see the*** **`SleepForFive()`** ***method?!?*** (If it's something really easy, then I'm going to have to eat my shorts). :)

Comment: So, it appears that my issue is that I'm using a "Web Site" instead of a "Web Application" -- the code is compiled "on the fly" and the .dll files containing the source code are all named "Web_App_@@@@@@@.dll".  E.g. the Assembly name isn't available until runtime... :(

Answer (score 0):

The `assemblyName` in the `<match />` node of the file cannot be blank. Set this to the namespace of your project. Do not add the `.Controllers` object. For instance, if my namespace were `SunnySideUp.Controllers` and my `className` was "Tastey_Eggs", it would look like this:

```
<match assemblyName="SunnySideUp" className="Tastey_Eggs">
```

Everything else in the custom instrumentation looks correct.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, for your answer. Per your suggestion, I've added a namespace to my page, but I was still unable to get it to work. :(  
The aspx.cs file now says: `namespace Sandbox { public partial class TestNewRelic : System.Web.UI.Page {`...  
The aspx file now says: ...`Inherits="Sandbox.TestNewRelic"`...  
And the Instrumentation file has: `<match assemblyName="Sandbox" className="TestNewRelic">`
I restarted IIS and recycled the app pool, but got the same result.  
I also tried it with `<match assemblyName="Sandbox.TestNewRelic" className="TestNewRelic">` to no avail.  
Any other ideas?